# remove everything before the last occurrence of a character

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to perform the following action on a string :

- find the last occurrence of the character `"/"`;
- remove everything before that character;
- return the remains of the string;

To be more explicit, let's say I have the following string :

```
var string = "/Roland/index.php"; // Which is a result of window.location.pathname
```

Now what I need to extract out of it is everything but the actual page, something like this :

```
var result = "index.php" // Which is what I need to be returned
```

Of course, that is just an example, because obviously I will have different pages, but the same principles apply.

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a solution for it. I tried the next actions but with no success :

```
var location = window.location.pathname;
var result = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf["/"]);
```

Comment: You were close. `lastIndexOf` is a function and you cannot override `location` if it is a global variable. So it should be: `loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf("/"))` and since you don't want to include the slash itself: `loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have the right idea just replace the brackets with parentheses.

```
var string = "/Roland/index.php";
var result = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ompr5f3w/) and here is an explanation of the .lastIndexOf() method on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

Comment: That would remove everything *after* the last occurrence. OP wants to remove everything *before*. It should actually be `location.substring(location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`.

Comment: That's what I'm using, except the `0` in there which would do the opposite of what I need :)

Comment: Sorry Roland, I misread  your question, and thought you wanted everything UPTO the slash. Yes, just remove the 0 param and you'll have what you want, your only problem was the incorrect brackets.

Comment: I think that Michael's answer is the better one here because you're going to encounter an exception if ever you pass in a string that has no "/" and the line will choke on the -1.  So, at the very least you'll want to protect with my edit...

Answer (score 15):

Personally I'd use a regular expression:

```
var result = string.replace(/^.*\/(.*)$/, "$1");
```

If you're familiar with regular expressions (and you should be if not :-)  then it's not as alien-looking as it is when they're unfamiliar.

The leading `^` forces this regular expression to "anchor" the match at the start of the string. The `\/` matches a single `/` character (the `\` is to keep the `/` from confusing the regular expression parser). Then `(.*)$` matches everything else from the `/` to the end of the string. The initial `.*` will swallow up as much as it can, including `/` characters before the last one. The replacement text, `"$1"`, is a special form that means "the contents of the first matched group". This regex has a group, formed by the parentheses around the last `.*` (in `(.*)$`). That's going to be all the stuff after the last `/`, so the overall result is that the whole string is replaced by just that stuff. (If the pattern doesn't match because there aren't any `/` characters, nothing will happen.)

Comment: No, I'm familiar with it, I'm using it in PHP but less in JS

Answer (score 10):

Split the string into an array on `/` and `.pop()` off the last element.  Note, that you will first need to strip off a trailing slash if there is one.

```
var locationstring = window.location.pathname;
// replace() the trailing / with nothing, split on the remaining /, and pop off the last one
console.log(locationstring.replace(/\/$/, "").split('/').pop());
```

If in the case of a URL like `/path/stuff/here/` where you have the trailing `/`, if that case should return an empty string rather than `here`, modify the above to remove the `.replace()` from the call chain.  I assumed you would want the last component regardless of a trailing slash, but may have incorrectly assumed.

```
console.log(locationstring.split('/').pop());
```

Comment: I think my solution is cleaner, but in any case you'd need to join that array back together on "/" or you'd wind up with pieces without the /.

Comment: I prefer not using `.pop()` :)

Comment: @Dr. Dredel the OP doesn't need the rest of the string, only the last part,  so no need to join it back together

Comment: oh, I misread the question (or maybe the OP edited? not sure) I thought he wanted everything UP TO the last slash.  Your approach is obviously fine for the stated question.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I agree, there was confusion in asking to "extract out of it everything up to" --  when you _extract_, you usually want to retain it, but in this case, it should have read "remove everything up to".

Answer (score 2):

```
    var result = /\/([^\/]*)$/.exec(location)[1];

//"remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character#10767835"
```

Note: `location` here is the `window.location`, not your `var location`.

Answer (score 1):

To know which one is the fastest I created a small benchmark. The regex is the slowest solution and using `substring` or `slice` with `lastIndexOf` is strictly faster than `split` with either `pop` or `at`.

so use:

```js
loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Complete result:

[image: result]

[Try it online!](http://jsben.ch/7x60l)

Answer (score -1):

```
var string = "/Roland/index.php";
var result = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf("/") + 0);
```