# JS remove everything after the last occurrence of a character

Tags: javascript

Okay I have this

```
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
console.log(URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Gives you "/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character"

How do I get "`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/`"

Comment: Do I get credit for the effort ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
alert(URL.substring(0, URL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add a link to some documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution **will return an empty string if there is no `/`** in the string we are searching in. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099330/1494454) for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a good case for a regular expression (can't believe no one has posted it yet):

```
URL.replace(/[^\/]+$/,'')
```

Removes all sequential non–forward slash characters to the end of the string (i.e. everything after the last /).

Answer (score 3):

### Generic solution

This is a generic function that also handles the edge case when the searched character or string (needle) is not found in the string we are searching in (haystack). It returns the original string in that case.

```js
function trimStringAfter(haystack, needle) {
  const lastIndex = haystack.lastIndexOf(needle)
  return haystack.substring(0, lastIndex === -1 ? haystack.length : lastIndex + 1)
}

console.log(trimStringAfter('abcd/abcd/efg/ggfbf', '/')) // abcd/abcd/efg/
console.log(trimStringAfter('abcd/abcd/abcd', '/')) // abcd/abcd/
console.log(trimStringAfter('abcd/abcd/', '/')) // abcd/abcd/
console.log(trimStringAfter('abcd/abcd', '/')) // abcd/
console.log(trimStringAfter('abcd', '/')) // abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";

console.log(URL.substring(0,URL.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
//The +1 is to add the last slash
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo9L1bcq/) or run the code snippet.

```js
    var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
    var myRegexp = /^(.*\/)/g;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(URL);
    alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: This solution will throw an error when there is no `/` in the string. Might not be a problem for URLs, but can cause issues if somebody uses it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(URL.substring(0, URL.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```js
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
var temp = URL.split('/');
temp.pop();
var result = temp.join('/');
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.match()` with `RegExp` `/^\w+.*\d+\//`

```js
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
var res = URL.match(/^\w+.*\d+\//)[0];
document.body.textContent = res;
```

Comment: This solution will throw an error when there is no `/` in the string. Might not be a problem for URLs, but can cause issues if somebody uses it for something else.

Answer (score -1):

Try an array based extraction like

```js
var URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767815/remove-everything-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character";
snippet.log(URL.split('/').slice(0, 5).join('/'));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<!-- To show result in the dom instead of console, only to be used in the snippet not in production -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will only work for that exact URL scheme. Add an extra slash somewhere and it returns the wrong result. If you really want to use this array based method you need to do `URL.split('/').slice(0, URL.split('/').length - 1).join('/');`

Comment: You are linking to a dead GitHub link.