# Removing last bit of a string including separator?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
Red#Yellow#Blue#Green
```

How can I use Javascript to remove the last instance of `#` as well as the text that comes after it, so that the resulting string would look like this:

```
Red#Yellow#Blue
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS remove everything after the last occurrence of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308281/js-remove-everything-after-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character)

Comment: @JJJ This is slightly different because this question also requests that the last character itself be removed as well.

Comment: If they can't adapt the duplicate's code to remove one extra character then perhaps they're not really cut for programming.

Comment: @JJJ that's the spirit of this community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string=string.split("#");
alert(string.pop());//Green
string=string.join("#");
```

I dont see a problem? Simply split by #, remove the last one and join again?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can split the string into arrays and join all the items of the array except the last one

```
var myString = Red#Yellow#Blue#Green;
var myArrray = myString.split('#');
myArray.splice(myArray.length-1,1);
myArray.join('#');
```

Comment: myArray.splice(myArray.length-1,1); is the same as pop() ... also your string isnt a string

Comment: yeah you're right that's why I voted your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('Red#Yellow#Blue#Green'.replace(/\#[a-zA-Z]+$/,''));
```